# How to define an Angular 2 component or directive with multiple selectors

Tags: css, angular

**Goal:**

Provide 'synonym' selectors for components and directives within my application.

**Motivation:**

There are times where a component or directive provides functionality that can be thought of in different ways whereas the name of the selector should meaningfully represent or simplify thinking about how the component or directive operates (the name being a mnemonic device).

**Research:**

### Directives

I had observed that Material 2 provides what seemed to be multiple selectors for its `MdList` and `MdListItem` directives:

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/list/list.ts

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'md-list, md-nav-list',
  host: {'role': 'list'},
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  styleUrls: ['list.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MdList {}
```

...and...

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'md-list-item, a[md-list-item]',
  host: {
    'role': 'listitem',
    '(focus)': '_handleFocus()',
    '(blur)': '_handleBlur()',
  },
  templateUrl: 'list-item.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MdListItem implements AfterContentInit {
    ...
}
```

From the Angular 2 attribute directives page in the documentation:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

> `@Directive` requires a CSS selector to identify the HTML in the template that
>       is associated with our directive. The CSS selector for an attribute is the
>       attribute name in square brackets. Our directive's selector is `[myHighlight]`.
>       Angular will locate all elements in the template that have an attribute named
>       `myHighlight`.

Which links to the following attribute selectors MDN page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

From the Angular 2 Cheat Sheet page:

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

[image]

---

The comma syntax of the Material 2 `list.ts` CSS selectors that I found, suggests that these apply to multiple situations - my evaluation of what these selectors are doing is:

1. `class MdList` applies to `md-list` and `md-nav-list` elements
2. `class MdListItem` applies to `md-list-item` and `a` elements that have a `md-list-item` attribute

### Components

From the Angular 2 Architecture Overview page:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html

> selector: CSS selector that tells Angular to create and insert an instance
>   of this component where it finds a `<hero-list>` tag in parent HTML. For 
>   example, if an app's HTML contains `<hero-list></hero-list>`, then Angular 
>   inserts an instance of the `HeroListComponent` view between those tags.`

Interestingly, in the wild, I have not come across any example of a component that has multiple selectors.

**Mental Model Misconceptions:**

When I was introduced to Angular 2 I "lazily" interpreted `selectors` merely as the name of the component or directive as represented within the application `HTML`.

In my (faulty) mental model component selectors where only a way of effectively defining an application specific `HTML` element.

In my (faulty) mental model directive selectors where only a way to define an application specific `HTML` element attribute serving to modify the behavior of the element.

Having done the research and having carefully studied (all of the words in) the documentation I have come to realize that there's something more powerful going on here...

**General Questions:**

1. Where have I got any of the above wrong?
2. What other aspects of component and directive selectors am I missing? e.g. is there more power to be harnessed here?

**Specific Questions:**

1. Can a component have element attribute selector? and if so, what would the behavior/effect be?
2. In which situations would you want a directive to have an element selector?
3. What's the syntax to apply a directive to synonym CSS attributes? e.g. apply a directive to any of a group of CSS attribute selectors...

Comment: Does it not work?

Comment: I'm learning here - there doesn't seem to be anything faulty in Angular 2

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "I'm learning here". Do you have a problem or is there none. Is this just a question? Have you actually tried it?

Comment: OK - maybe there is a problem - I have a selector `[vx-top-left], [vx-left-top]` which is intended to match elements that have a `vx-top-left` or `vx-left-top` attribute - when I define / declare just one attribute selector it works, but when I define / declare both together Angular does not find the elements that I'm expecting it to... my post is conservative under the assumption that I'm just not understanding (as opposed to believing that there's a problem with Angular 2)

Comment: That should just work. It's used in a lot of directives in Angular2 itself.

Comment: That was my guess too... I may be having caching and/or IDE issues that are confusing my situation (I'm getting some weird (indeterminate) behaviors)... nonetheless, it's good that you are able to confirm that my understanding regarding how this works is now more accurate... thanks

Answer (score 8):

> Where have I got any of the above wrong?

> "lazily" interpreted selectors

I don't know about lazily interpreted selectors.

If a tag that matches a selector or a component is found in a components template, then it is upgraded to an Angular component.
If `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` is used (like the router does) to add a component dynamically, then a tag that matches the selector is added to the DOM and the component applied to it.

> In my (faulty) mental model component selectors where only a way of effectively defining an application specific HTML element.

Selectors are for matching a DOM element with a component or directive for Angular to know what part of the DOM should become a component or directive.

> What other aspects of component and directive selectors am I missing? e.g. is there more power to be harnessed here?

> Can a component have element attribute selector? and if so, what would the behavior/effect be?

You can use custom tag names, attributes, and CSS classes and any combination of these. You can't use `id` or selectors that span multiple elements. With `,` separated multiple selectors can be used where the component is added to elements where one of these matches.
Many of Angulars built-in directives use a list of selectors.

> In which situations would you want a directive to have an element selector?

A directive is the same as a component, just without it's own view.

```
<my-dropdown>
  <my-item></my-item>
  <my-item></my-item>
  <my-item></my-item>
</my-dropdown>
```

Could be implemented by a component like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dropdown',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
```

or

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'my-dropdown',
})
```

and they would do exactly the same.

> What's the syntax to apply a directive to synonym CSS attributes? e.g. apply a directive to any of a group of CSS attribute selectors...

```
selector: '[attr1],[attr2],[attr3]'
```